# Post to my Page's wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an application that lets users post content to their walls. I would like to dual post the content my Page's wall as well (so users of the app can see it being used around Facebook). This seems to work by making two Graph requests, *however the posts get marked as spam* and I need to go in and approve them. The user may or may not have "liked" my Page, but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Is there way to exclude my app from the spam filtering, or a better way of doing this?

Comment: double posting IS spam... maybe you could post a link to the users wall post on your pages wall.

Comment: Good point  - I might try going down that route instead

Comment: i'd say its your best bet - facebook will retrieve all descriptions, pictures, links that are in the post and display them.  It will essentially have the exact same functionality as a post.

Comment: I presume you mean simply posting the Perma-Link to the user's wall on my page's wall? If the user has their post set to "friends only" this will of course not work (I was planning on making this an option so the user would be aware their messages were also going to the App's wall). - Worth exploring, I guess I would need to detect the privacy settings and only re-post if it was public?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get an permanent access-token that will let you post as the admin of the page (for posting to your pages wall) and then the post should not need moderating.

See http://www.sergiy.ca/post-on-facebook-app-wall-and-fan-page-wall-as-admin/

Comment: Thanks Tim. I wanted the post to appear to be "from" the original user, the idea being to somehow link users to my page's wall. Will this allow me to specify that user as the 'From' ?  Thanks again.